# queryselector is returning incorrect value for input field

Tags: javascript, html

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function displayquestion(a, ignore){
    var b = a-1;
    var currentInput = '';
    var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("questionholder");
    var showRequired = document.getElementById("requiredMessage");

    if (document.querySelector('input.input' + b) !== null) {
        var currentInput = document.querySelector('input.input' + b).value;
    }

    // Check if question should ignore inputs
    if (ignore == 1) { // yes, ignore the inputs so move on to next question
        console.log("path 1");
        showRequired.style.display = "none";        

        for(var i=0; i < questions.length; i++) {           
            questions[i].style.display = "none";    
        }

        var nextQuestion = document.getElementById("question" + a);

        if(nextQuestion !== null) {
            nextQuestion.style.display = "block";
        }   
    } else { //no, don't ignore the inputs
        if (currentInput == '') { // the input is blank so show error
            console.log("path 2");

            showRequired.style.display = "block";
        } else { // the input is not blank so move on to next question
            console.log("currentInput = " + currentInput);

            showRequired.style.display = "none";        

            for(var i=0; i < questions.length; i++) {           
                questions[i].style.display = "none";    
            }

            var nextQuestion = document.getElementById("question" + a);

            if(nextQuestion !== null) {
                nextQuestion.style.display = "block";
            }   
        }
    }
}   
</script>
</head>

<body>  
<div id="requiredMessage" style="display:none"><p>This field is required.</p></div>

<form id="TheForm" style="display:block;">
<div data-toggle="buttons" class="questionholder multiplechoice" id="question10" style="display:block">
    <h5>Do you have a surname?</h5>
    <input class="input10" type="radio" id="yes" name="sn" value="yes"><label for="relPPTsnyes"><p class="radioChoice">Yes / Oui</p></label>
    <input class="input10" type="radio" id="no" name="sn" value="no"><label for="relPPTsnno"><p class="radioChoice">No / Non</p></label><br>        
    <a class="text2button radio" onclick="displayquestion(11)">Next</a>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have issues with my javascript function, which works as intended with input text fields, but does not with radio buttons.

In short, I have a div that contains a pair of radio buttons and a next button. When the user click next, the function displayquestion(a) fires.

The function checks currentInput to see if the input is blank. If it is blank, it shows an error message. If it is not blank, it hides the div.

With radio buttons however, currentInput is always returning "yes" whether nothing is selected, no is selected or yes is selected. Since it isn't blank, it hides the div.

The intended result should be that the error message displays until the user makes a selection. only when the user clicks next, it should hide the div.

So my question is, what is causing my issue and how can it be fixed?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mvcu7wqb/2/)

Comment: Well you need to see if one of them is checked...

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
if (document.querySelector('input.input' + b).type == "radio") { //this is a radio input                
    if (document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked')) { //a radio option is selected                 
        showNext();

    } else { // no radio option is selected so show error       
            showRequired.style.display = "block";
    }               
} else { // not a radio input

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use :checked

```
var currentInput = document.querySelectorAll('input.input' + b + ':checked").value;
```

Comment: this only works if one of the radiobuttons is checked. if none fo them are checked, I get an error

Answer (score 0):

you not checking whether the radio is checked or not.As a result `document.querySelector` returns the first radio with `value = "yes"` use **[:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)** is querySelector

```
if (document.querySelector('input.input' + b + ':checked') !== null) {
        currentInput = document.querySelector('input.input' + b + ':checked').value;
        console.log(currentInput)
    }
```

Comment: the issue here is that if none of the radio buttons is selected, I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: @Sweepster it can't get error because you are first checking if its not `null` is `if` condition. And then you are accessing its `value`. The code you have provided works fine

Comment: but your code is only checking if checked inputs are not null. This function needs to run on text inputs as well, therefore I need to check wheterh the input is a text or radio input first, and that's returning errors

Comment: The error on your fiddle happens because in line 14 you check for `'input.input' + b` (`if (document.querySelector('input.input' + b) !== null)`) but in line 15 you get the value of `'input.input' + b + ':checked'`. Just add the `':checked'` in the if.

Answer (score 0):

Radios and Checkboxes always return their value.
The first thing you must do is check if one of them is selected, then get the value of the selected one.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]') // or type=radio
for (const input of inputs)
{
    if (input.checked)
    {
        console.log(input.value)
    }
}
```

Also, `querySelector()` can return the selected one directly, without the need to loop the node list.

```
const input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]:checked') // or type=radio
if (input)
{
    console.log(input.value)
}
```

Comment: console.log(document.querySelector('input[type=radio]') == true); is returning false for me. How can I check whether a radio input exists at all?

Comment: If your equality check is returning false, that means that `querySelector()` couldn't find elements that match the supplied selector. This means that the element doesn't exist. If your selector is `input[type=checkbox]:checked`, then, no checked checkbox  exists.

Comment: if yes or no are selected, I get the correct values, but if none are selected I get an error